# bind mount /dev/pts twice - umount fails with "target is busy."

Tags: linux, mount

I'm trying to understand problems that I get when I run my `debootstrap` procedure more than once in parallel. It seems to come down to this piece of bash script:

```
DIR1=/mnt/foo$RANDOM
DIR2=/mnt/foo$RANDOM
mkdir -p "$DIR1" "$DIR2"
mount -o bind /dev "$DIR1"
mount -o bind /dev/pts "$DIR1/pts"
mount -o bind /dev "$DIR2"
mount -o bind /dev/pts "$DIR2/pts"
umount "$DIR1/pts"
umount "$DIR1"
```

Do you have an idea why the last line fails (at least on my Debian bullseye system) with "target is busy."?

When I add `-l` to the `umount` for lazy unmounting, it gets even worse: My system ends up with `/dev/pts` not mounted anymore. I have to mount it again manually or reboot then.

Answer (score 1):

Don't mount /dev/pts via binding, instead mount it per se:

```bash
mount -t devpts none "$DIR1/pts"
```